# VB.Net: Putting Contents of One List into Another

Tags: vb.net, list, for-loop, recursion, instantiation

Given two lists:

`Dim listOfCollectiveTasks As New List(Of String)
 Dim listOfCollectiveTasks2 As New List(Of String)`

I am adding elements to `listOfCollectiveTasks2`, and then trying to delete the contents of `listOfCollectiveTasks`... afterwards putting the contents of `listOfCollectiveTasks2` into it.

Code:

```
Public Sub testRecursive()
    For Each atask In listOfCollectiveTasks
        getRemainingSupportingTask(getTaskID(atask), "Collective")
        'getRemainingSupportingTask(atask, "Individual")
    Next


    listOfCollectiveTasks = Nothing
    For Each item In listOfCollectiveTasks2
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString)
    Next
    listOfCollectiveTasks.Concat(listOfCollectiveTasks2)
    testRecursive()

End Sub

Public Sub getRemainingSupportingTask(theID As String, collectiveOrSupporting As String)
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim listOfTasks As New List(Of String)
    Dim theQuery As String = "Select * from [SupportingTask$] where [TaskID] = "
    theQuery = theQuery + "'" + theID + "'" + " and [SupportingTaskTypeName] = " + "'" + collectiveOrSupporting + "'"
    rs = MyADO.executeQuery(theQuery)
    Console.WriteLine(theQuery)


    Do Until rs.EOF
        Dim theString As String = rs.Fields("SupportingTaskNumber").Value
        If String.Equals(collectiveOrSupporting, "Collective") Then

            listOfCollectiveTasks2.Add(theString)



            Console.WriteLine(theString)
            newXlSheet.Cells(lastCollectiveRow, 1) = theString
            lastCollectiveRow = lastCollectiveRow + 1


        Else
            'listOfIndividualTasks.Add(theString)
            Console.WriteLine(theString)
            newXlSheet.Cells(lastIndividualRow, 2) = theString
            lastIndividualRow = lastIndividualRow + 1

        End If
        rs.MoveNext()
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
    Console.WriteLine("")



End Sub
```

I'm getting a `System.ArgumentNullException` on `listOfCollectiveTasks.Concat(listOfCollectiveTasks2). I can't figure out a way of putting the items from list2 into list1.

Comment: What is the exit condition of your recursive function?

Comment: When `listOfCollectiveTasks` is empty

Comment: That might be what you want to happen, but that's not what's going to happen. Currently, you've got an infinite loop. Furthermore, you've got a `NullReferenceException` since you assigned `Nothing` to `listOfCollectiveTasks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have to do some after market or before market operation it is more efficient to just add a range with System.Type collections.  Then clear the originating list of the appends.  Like so:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ls1 = New List(Of String)({"a", "b", "c", "d"})
    Dim ls2 = New List(Of String)
    Dim ls3 = New List(Of String)({"e", "f"})

    ls2.AddRange(ls1)
    ls1.Clear()

    ls2.AddRange(ls3)
    ls3.Clear()

    Console.WriteLine($"Count of List1: {ls1.Count}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Count of List2: {ls2.Count}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Count of List3: {ls3.Count}")
    ls2.ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```